# Build works, but media play doesn't seem to load

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

i'm working on an android app at the moment that has the purpose of playing a particular song at exactly midnight. I know that there might already be apps in the appstore that serve that purpose, but I'm new to coding and wanted to try to program the app myself.
So now I reached the point where I don't know what to do anymore. I tried debugging the App on my LG H818P running Android 6.0. It posted, The Icon, the Name and everything were correct,  but i didn't play the song, even when i set the time when it should've played it to two minutes after the start if the building.

So that's the code of the MainActivity.cs in Visual Studio 2017, can anyone find any errors?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Media;

namespace Name of the App
{
    [Activity(Label = "Name of the App", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity


    {
        string text = "status";
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

        {


        }

        public void main()
        {
            try
            {

                string systemtime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)
                {
                    if (systemtime == "09:07:00 pm")
                    {
                        StartPlayer();
                        player.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                text = "Error!";
            }
        }

        protected MediaPlayer player;
        public void StartPlayer()
        {
            if (player == null)
            {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.SetDataSource("Ressources.raw.file2beplayed.mp3");
                player.Prepare();
                player.Start();
                text = "Playing!";
            }
            else
            {
                player.Reset();
                player.SetDataSource("Ressources.raw.file2beplayed.mp3");
                player.Prepare();
                player.Start();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

As I said, I'm a Noob in coding, so sorry for the maybe ugly code :)
Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Yes, looks a bit like you are new to this. :) Remove your for loop completely and it will work.  You are basically never executing the startplayer() method because i is initialized to 0, and this loop only executes while i is greater than 0.  Why have the for loop at all here?

Answer (score 0):

The default format for `ToString` in a `DateTime` is `MM/dd/yyyy`, so your comparation `systemtime == "09:07:00 pm"` will never be true.

You can use a `TimeSpan` and the property `TimeOfDay` from `DateTime`;

```
if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == new Timespan(21,7,0))
  //...
```

Also, your loop will never be executed as you initialize `i` as 0, so at the first check `i` will not be greater than 0 so the loop isn't executed.

Finally, Android does not use the `main` function, is an special type of program, your initialization code should be in the `OnCreate` function, but if you create an infinite loop in that function Android will close the application as it will not finish it's initialization, you need to use a timer and check the condition each second.

Comment: Thanks for the hints with the for loop and the time, that kinda worked i guess :D But do you have any idea why the Media Player still isn't starting? I'm always altering the time btw, so it matches with the time I'm exporting the build

Comment: Sorry, without seeing your new code I can't guess what problem has.

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid of me ;) I uploaded the new code to pastebin, becaus it had been to long for a comment  https://pastebin.com/kEmt2KdA